# Can not open .aco file in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop

I downloaded a color palette from dribbble. Specifically, the one from

http://dribbble.com/shots/665606-The-Design-Blog?list=users

(click on the tear drop icon next to the color palette)

The file is a .aco file which when I open in Photoshop (Adobe Photoshop CS6, version 13.0.1 x64), Photoshop complains about unexpected end of file:

[image]

Is it possible to figure out what is wrong with the file or if there is something I need to do in Photoshop to be able to open these type of files?

Thanks.

Comment: The file is possibly wrong, have you tried again with another download from the same site?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded a few other palettes and get the same error in Photoshop.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was opening the file by double clicking on it and then Photoshop would be the application that would be default try to open it and then give me this error.

It appears what I needed to all along was go to the Swatches window in Photoshop, click on it's menu and the select Load Swatches:

[image]

Then browse to the .aco file and select it and it then loads fine :)